# MySql Order by not showing correct results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I have 3 tables projects, discussion & comments. projects have multiple discussions and each discussion have multiple comments.

I want to get the last discussion added to the discussions table which doesn't have a comment. And i also need the project details to which that particular discussion is linked to.

My query goes like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.PRO_Id, p.PRO_Name,
    d.DIS_ThreadDesc, dev.DEV_Name, loc.LOC_Name, d.USE_Id, d.DIS_Date

    FROM projects p
    LEFT JOIN discussions d ON p.PRO_Id = d.PRO_Id
    LEFT JOIN developer dev ON p.DEV_Id=dev.DEV_Id
    LEFT JOIN locality loc  ON p.LOC_Id=loc.LOC_Id
        WHERE 
            p.PRO_Status=1 and d.DIS_Status=1 
            AND d.DIS_Id NOT IN ( select DIS_Id from comments where COM_Status=2 )
        GROUP BY p.PRO_Id
        ORDER  BY d.DIS_Id desc LIMIT 3
```

I'm ordering the discussion table by descending (ORDER BY d.DIS_Id) but still it takes the first record instead of the last record. What i'm doing wrong here??

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: ok i will try to put a sqlfiddle for more clarification.

Comment: Do you want the last discussion in each project?

Comment: yes that is what im looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.PRO_Id, p.PRO_Name, d.DIS_ThreadDesc, dev.DEV_Name, 
       loc.LOC_Name, d.USE_Id, d.DIS_Date
FROM projects p
INNER JOIN discussions d ON p.PRO_Id = d.PRO_Id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT d.PRO_Id, MAX(d.DIS_Id) lastDisc 
            FROM discussions d  
            WHERE d.DIS_Status = 1 
            GROUP BY d.PRO_Id
          ) AS A ON d.PRO_Id = A.PRO_Id AND d.DIS_Id = A.lastDisc 
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments c ON d.DIS_Id = c.DIS_Id AND c.COM_Status=2 
LEFT OUTER JOIN developer dev ON p.DEV_Id = dev.DEV_Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN locality loc ON p.LOC_Id = loc.LOC_Id
WHERE p.PRO_Status = 1 AND c.DIS_Id IS NULL
ORDER BY d.DIS_Id DESC;
```

Comment: yes yes thats im looking for that exactly..

Comment: @Mr Shah For such questions should i put sqlfiddle for more accuracy or had my question already given you all a  clear cut description of my requirement.

Comment: @Plum It is good if you add demo with sample data so that every one can understand what is the problem that you're facing...

Comment: @Mr Shah Ok i will take that advice when trying to put my next ques@.